# How to regenerate Hibernate Model classes from database on netbeans

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, pojo

I have a running application developed on netbeans using hibernate and it works fine now I added some parameter to a database table and I want to reflect these changes on my generated hibernate classes how to achieve so ?

Comment: Why would you use a different way than the way you used to generate the code the first time?

Comment: fixed the issue  by using hbm2ddl tool

<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

achieved so by the inverse way so I updated the code to update the databse accordingly using hbm2ddl tool
by adding this

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: This will update the database schema based on changes in your code. You asked how to do the exact inverse thing.

Comment: Yes exactly I wonder do you have a way to update classes from DB I couldn't find any.

Comment: As I already asked: why don't you use the same way as the first time you generated the classes? And why are you answering your own question with a wrong answer?

Comment: then delete them and regenerate them. Or do the right thing, and learn to write code by yourself rather than relying on dumb tools.

Comment: I am new to hibernate I am entityframework originated
what do you by dumb tools ?  hbm2ddl ?

Comment: NetBeans. The entities are the heart and soul of your project. They're used everywhere. They should be well-documented, and contain custom methods. You shouldn't generate them. hbm2ddl is fine for quick and dirty protoyping. You shouldn't use that to generate, and even less migrate, your database schema. Use SQL scripts, or Liquibase, or FlywayDB

Comment: I got you ! thank you so much for this precious advice.. I will remove the code and regenerate it as you advised